# PHP - How to login via curl and download files?

Tags: php, curl, http-authentication

Im using php, using curl Im accessing a directory on a server via http using httpauth. I pass it a username and password and it seems to work, but once I login how do I get the current directory and then proceed to download the files in that directory? Im using this curl code to authenticate:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just resend the credentials for any future requests. HTTP authentication doesn't keep track of logins; the client simply needs to resend the username / password pair for each request.

Comment: The problem is I dont know whats in the directory, I just know I need to download all files in that directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can grab the directory index first to get the file list, then get the files individually by looping through that list. Parsing the list of files from the HTML is a different issue altogether.

Comment: Are you saying download the page first then parse it for the html links and then loop through each link found?

Comment: Yes, unless you have some easier way to get the directory listing.

Comment: Nope feel like an idiot not figuring this out. I was using $info instead of $output. Thanks a bunch!